# Perturbation theory expansion in matrix size instead of elements

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, perturbation-theory

Suppose I know the eigenvalues and eigenvectors of an N-dimensional matrix M exactly. Now, I add a perturbation $\delta$ to just the (N, N) element of the matrix, M. In other words, the perturbation matrix is diag $(0,0,...\delta)$. The perturbation $\delta$ is real, positive and $\mathcal{O}(1)$.

Intuitively, I would expect that the perturbation's effect on the eigenvalues would decrease as the size of the matrix increases, as it affects only one element of a large matrix (even if $\delta$ is $\mathcal{O}(1)$). Some quick numerical plots for sample matrices suggest this as well. **Is there a way to set up a formal expansion of the eigenvalues in $1/N$ to show this?**

If it helps, the problem I am working on involves M being a real symmetric tridiagonal matrix, with most of the elements in each diagonal being equal (except for the (1, 1) and (N, N) elements). I have tried some of the common techniques for tackling tridiagonal Toeplitz matrices on this, but I have not been able to diagonalise it because of the end elements being different. I have a complete solution for the case in which $a = c + d$, but with arbitrary end elements $c$ and $d$, it seems to be insoluble.

$$M =
\begin{pmatrix}
  c & b & 0 & 0 & \cdots  \\
  b & a & b & 0 &\cdots \\
  0 & b & a & b &\cdots \\
  \vdots & & \ddots & \ddots &  \ddots  \\
  0 & & & b & a &  b  \\
  0 & & \cdots & &  b & d
 \end{pmatrix}$$

Comment: By $\mathcal{O}(1)$ do you mean of the same magnitude as $a, b$ ? I think  a problem like this arises when calculating the vibrational modes of a chain of masses and springs. Your perturbation is like perturbing an end mass. I don't have any intuition whether this would affect the low or high frequencies differently. As for "formal expansion of the eigenvalues in $1/N$", I can't think how to do that even in physicist-math, since there is not a discrete spectrum for $N \to \infty$.

Comment: I tried using the same methods that are traditionally used to solve mass and spring chain systems, but they did not give me a solvable equation for the eigenvalues. As I stated in the question, it is exactly solvable for one particular case, and I could not do it in general. And yes, that's what I meant by $\mathcal{O}(1)$. 

An infinitely large matrix would essentially mean solving the bulk part for its eigenvalues, which I can try. That is essentially the starting point of the spring and mass system method. However, my N is not so large that this is useful.

Comment: In case this might be useful for anyone else: I got a fairly workable formula for the regime I was interested in using the method described [here](http://best.eng.buffalo.edu/Research/Seminar%20slides/pre_L5_Zack.pdf). I set up the characteristic equation in terms of differences between perturbed and unperturbed eigenvalues, and the differences ended up having a $1/N$ expansion, with some reasonable assumptions on the value of $b$.